# Is factor ring field?

Tags: factoring, division-ring

There is defined

Z[i] = {a+bi|a,b $\in$ Z}

with standard operations of addition and multiplications complex number. Question is, if factor ring
Z[i]/(1-i) is field. How could I prove it? Do you have any hint?

Comment: No, it's not. This would mean it's a field, since it's a commutative ring. Actually, it's isomorphic to $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard Assuming $i$ isn't a free variable, but instead $i^2=-1$ (which seems reasonable seeing as complex numbers are mentioned), you're wrong. Hint to Aladar90: $2\in (1-i)$.

Comment: @Arthur sorry I made a mistake. I need to prove if it is field, no division ring.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(1-i^2)$?

Comment: Does $1-i$ generate a maximal ideal?

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1: We have $2=(1-i)(1+i)$, so in $\Bbb Z[i]/(1-i)$, we have $2=1-i=2i=0$. It doesn't take much work from here to see that the ring has two elements, and what the multiplication in this ring is.

Approach 2: We have $\Bbb Z[i]\cong \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$, so $\Bbb Z[i]/(1-i)\cong\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2+1, 1-x)$. Now figure out which ring this is by dividing out by first $(1-x)$, and then $(x^2+1)$ instead of the other way around.